# Error while Patching Security Patch (SUPEE-6285)

Tags: security, patches, supee-6285

While trying to patch magento, which I have done a few times now with prior patches successfully, I encountered an issue with this latest patch.

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/Mage.php
patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 99 (offset 1 line).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml.rej
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 894
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|index 43698c2..f4fe5ab 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
patching file errors/processor.php
```

So my first move is to go look at the .rej files it creates which I assume declare what the disconnects are. However the file isn't there. Which led me to think possibly the folder doesn't have write access, but it does. So I am confused as to what could be going wrong, any ideas?

Magento Version: CE 1.9.0.1

Patch: PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-07-07-09-03-34.sh

Also; It is stated with the patch that you must first implement SUPEE-5994 to ensure SUPEE-6285 works properly, which I have already done.

**EDIT**: Turns out at some point, I deleted the /modern/ folder when it wasn't being used. Replacing that removed the cart.phtml issue, however the noItems.phtml issue still persists.

Comment: You probably have a modification inside app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml, open the downloaded patch file and see which changes is the patch introducing in the file.

Comment: Turns out that default/modern folder wasn't being used, so at some point down the road I just deleted it. However I readded it, and it got rid of the issue regarding that cart.phtml, but the noItems.phtml issue still persists, while that file is surely there, yet still no reject file being created either.

Comment: Also have the same error here, i cant remember that i have made any changes to the cart

Comment: Update: I have solved the error by downloading my current magento version on  https://www.magentocommerce.com/download (ver 1910) and have uploaded the whole  /design/frontend/default/modern/ directory to my website.

Comment: Same problem here, running Magento 1.9 Hunk #1 FAILED at 33. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED

Comment: this file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml` was modified or is coming incomplete from an old version of magento

Comment: Oddly enough, I replaced the cart file and never thought to replace the noItems.phtml with a fresh copy, but that did the trick. Thanks ADM & all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference, if patches can't be applied, check:

1. Are you using the right patch version for your Magento version?
2. Do the files that the patch fails to update present or have they been changed? Replace them with original files from your Magento version and apply the patch again